# About moving transparent, boderless wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, transparent

I am making a window with

```
WindowStyle="None"
AllowsTransparency="True"
Background="Transparent"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
ResizeMode="NoResize"
```

then I made a button other to move the window, using `this.DragMove();`, I put it into some event: `MouseDown` (of the button), `LeftbutonDown` (of the button) and `LeftbutonDown` (of the form), but still can not move the form.
My function:

```
private void btCurDate_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.DragMove();
}
```

(the button are defined Click event to do something else).  My running form:[image]

Comment: You can add a small border with a solid background (not transparent),  which has about the same size as the `btnCurDate`, and handle `MouseDown` event on the border. Border does not `intercept` mouse click event so your event handler will work as expected.

Comment: I try this <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
            </Border.Background>. Thus, i can move the form but now i can not click the button